# How to cache dependency of a detached gradle configuration on CI?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to generate a **full cache of dependencies** for all project/scripts configurations before `assemble` step. I'd like to use `--offline` gradle flag for all jobs except the caching one.

So android plugin provides `androidDependencies` task which resolves all resolvable dependencies of a project

Previously we used a custom task which does the same:

```
task resolveDependencies {
    description "Resolves all projects dependencies from the repository."
    group "Build Server"

    doLast {
        rootProject.allprojects { project ->
            project.buildscript.configurations.forEach { configuration ->
                if (configuration.canBeResolved) {
                    try {
                        configuration.resolve()
                    } catch (ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }

            project.configurations.forEach { configuration ->
                if (configuration.canBeResolved) {
                    try {
                        configuration.resolve()
                    } catch (ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unluckily some gradle scripts which are activated during `assemble` step use [detachedConfigurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640051/why-use-gradle-detached-configurations). These configurations are not visible and solved neither with `androidDependencies` task nor with the custom one

For example, android gradle build plugin throws the error during `assemble` step:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
        > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable$Params_Decorated@3d617643 of type Aapt2CompileRunnable.Params
        > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:7.1.3-7984345.
        Required by:
        project :app
        > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:7.1.3-7984345 available for offline mode.
```

Is it possible to solve all detached configurations before the `assemble` task?

For now the only solution i see is to cache dependencies as well after the `assemble` task and forget about using `--offline`

Please also check [related topic](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/recommended-dependencies-caching-for-a-gradle-setup-is-wrong/20712/3) on circleCi forum

Comment: Could you provide some background on what you need to achieve this? Are you trying to create a fat archive?

Comment: @GreenSaguaro Nope, i just want to cache everything what i need for a build in one setup job and then use --offline flag everywhere

Comment: I don't think you will be able to control the detached configurations.